# Trouble with PyAutoGUI in Python: Seeking Assistance for Specific Issue

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to write a robotic automation. I managed to open the required app, but when the login interface appears on the screen, I cannot fill in the login information in the input fields. In fact, I think this robotic application does not even see the login screen.

I have one more question related to the subject. When I try to open the application on my computer, I get the 'Do you allow the unknown application to make changes?' message appears and I intervene here and press the yes button. I don't want to do this manually, it's a problem I need to solve as part of the robotic action...your text

```
import pygetwindow as gw
import pyautogui
import time

class SKPS_ROBOT():
    def __init__(self):
        self.usurname = 'usuername'
        self.password = 'password'

    def open_app(self):
        pyautogui.press('winleft')
        pyautogui.write('SkpsPro')
        pyautogui.press('enter')

    def login(self):
        pyautogui.write(self.usurname)
        pyautogui.press('tab') 

        pyautogui.press('enter')


# Obje oluştur.
skps_robot = SKPS_ROBOT()

# Uygulamayayı aç
skps_robot.open_app()

# Giriş yap
skps_robot.login()

print('PRogram sonlandı')
```